# Implementing Active Miller Clamp

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, protection, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

I am using [UCC21732](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc21732-q1.pdf?ts=1603535929159&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) gate driver IC. This has an external miller clamp, meaning the "Clamp" pin must be connected to the Gate of the external MOSFET. However, I want to build my own miller clamp without the external clamp MOSFET.

So I looked at what an "internal miller clamp" does. I found [this](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/optoelectronics/gate-driver-photocouplers/articles/overcurrent-protection-function-vce-sat-detection-and-built-in-active-miller-clamp-function.html) document showing the internal diagram in detail. My question is -- Is the "Vclamp" simply a voltage source? Like, a cell battery? In other words, if I were to compare the voltage across gate resistor, how do I get the reference voltage? Should I be using something like a resistor divider?

[image: clamp]

EDIT:
I want to implement the active miller clamp without using the clamp pin in the gate driver. I have tried out using a pnp/npn transistor, but that is only to pull down the gate voltage to ground. Any suggestions on a different method is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AN-5073.pdf.pdf

Comment: @G36 Yes I have already tried the 2 methods mentioned, my supervisor says that I must implement the "logic" of active miller clamp instead of using the pin, so I'm assuming that means I must have a comparator with reference, that connected to gate of clamp mosfet. Something like this maybe?

Comment: So you need to implement a Fig 6 method?

Comment: @G36 yes, so I looked at the doc in my post, and I can't seem to understand how to get the Vclamp. I want to understand how the clamp function is working in this TLP5214A.

Comment: It seems like the "clamp circuit" is measuring the Vge voltage of low side IGBT and if this voltage is lower than 2.5V when low side IGBT is in turn-off "process" the internal transistor gets triggered to discharge Cgc capacitor. And "clamp circuit" is only triggered at the falling edge.